# Maintaining an embedded array with top 3 elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently working on a mobile car racing game.

After a user finishes a track, a new document is added to "Plays" collections.

Also, if the user finishes the track 3rd/2nd/1st in time. the user id and time will be added to the "best" array of this track. (and the new 4th place user will be removed from the array).

Since 2+ users can finish a track on the same time, I'll probably need to make this atomic. so I've used findAndModify.

So far I've managed to do it well if I only maintain the 1st position in the array. this is what I did:

```
db.collection('tracks').findAndModify(
    { $or: [ {_id: track_id, 'best': {$exists: false}}, {_id: track_id,'best.0.time': {$gt: _time}} ] },
    [],
    {$set : {'best.0' : {'user_id': _userId, 'time': _time} }},
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) return app_res.send(err);

      app_res.send (data.value != null);
      }
    );
```

But My goal is to maintain the 3 best.
I've looked in the MongoDB documentation for array operators but I can't understand how (and if) they can't help me achieve my goal.

Is there anyway I can do it?

**EDIT:** Just to make this more clear, the top 3 indicates the top 3 users and their top times. for example, if "best" array is:

```
1. user: a, time : 5.
2. user: b, time : 9.
3. user: c, time : 20.
```

and than **user c** finish the track in **7 seconds**, than "best" changes to:

```
1. user: a, time : 5.
2. user: c, time : 7.
3. user: b, time : 9.
```

---

My Schema:

Users:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "123"
  },
  "name": "A name"
}
```

Tracks:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "765"
  },
  "name": "A track name",
  "length": 34.65,
  "best": [{"user_id": 467,"time": 24},{"user_id": 532,"time": 47},{"user_id": 953,"time": 89}]
}
```

Plays:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "1"
  },
  "time": 300000,
  "date": {
    "$date": "2018-08-15T14:05:47.872Z"
  },
  "user_id": {
    "$oid": "123"
  },
  "track_id": {
    "$oid": "765"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you'd do that - using some special [modifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#push-modifiers) that can be used with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#push):

```
db.tracks.update({}, {
    $push: {
        "best": {
            $each: [ {"user_id": 123,"time": 1} ], // add a new item to the "best" array
            $slice: 3, // keep only top three
            $sort: { "time": 1 } // rank/sort based on "time" field
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That worked! thanks.
Is there anyway to keep the top three with distinct user_id? because I want to keep the top 3 users with their top record time. (and not the top 3 plays)
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible using plain MongoDB server-side code, at least not as long as this JIRA hasn't been resolved: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13841 That said (and without any knowledge around your specific game), my personal expectation of a highscore would be anyway that if I break it three times I'll be on 1st, 2nd and 3rd place... I'd feel shortchanged if my success would simply get ignored just because I've got an entry in the highscore already but I was actually faster...

Comment: It wouldn't get ignored, the goal is to keep the 3 best players and their best highscores, so if you broke your record, it would be updated. and if you were also beat a player, your entry will be pushed before him in the array.